# Batch program that moves files from one folder to another every 5 minutes

Tags: batch-file

I need a Batch program that moves files from one folder to another every 5 minutes (like an infinite loop until the batch program is closed manually). 
We have to upload file to our application via an application called Re-route. But the folder from where Re-route picks up the files is placed at another drive which is not accessible to the entire team the same being critical in terms of the documents it holds. So the files are placed by the team members at a common drive from where the Team Lead (who has access to the other drive from where the files are picked up by Re-Route) moves them to the actual Re-Route drive. And this consumes a lot of productive time since the same has to be done every 5 mins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Regards,
Vivek

Comment: your question is very much unclear.
1. you want a batch program?
2. you want to have separate permission for your logic?
3. you want to save bandwidth?
Please be clear with requirement. See someone already downvoted your questions, may be due this this reason only.

Comment: I tried to make myself very much clear. Anyways, here's what I need.
A Batch program that can move files from one folder another every 5 mins (or any time interval of my choice)

Comment: Why don't you just give Re-route access to the common drive? If it's on a different machine just map the drive.

Comment: That can't be done for some security reasons which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: I just need to use the below command every 5 mins in an infinite loop (i.e. the batch program is always running).

move d:\abc\XXX d:\cef\XXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna try this.. I'm assuming that your moving text files from one folder to another. The below code would do it at an interval of 10 secs using the TIMEOUT function in DOS. You can alter the time (in secs) as per your requirement. Its so simple!! This question should have been answered by now.

@echo
:home
TIMEOUT /T 10 /NOBREAK
cls
move "D:\Batch\1*.txt" "D:\Batch\2"
cls
Goto :home

Comment: Bingo. This is what I wanted. Thanks crunkhunk.

Answer (score 0):

OK as per my understanding here is the solution for you.
1. create a specific user, that has access to the location. and with that credential you would run your batch program.
 
2. you more a less want a scheduler. Have a look to quartz [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

Or you can use TimeTask given by Java. You can modify below progam as per your need.
Example is as given below.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimerTest{
   private Timer timer;

    public TimerTest() {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new PrintTask(), 5*60*1000);
    }

    class PrintTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
          //  System.out.println("Timer task is printing..");
          //  timer.cancel(); 
          //write file copy logic here.
          // see - Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING); 
          // see java nio APIs
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TimerTest(5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Quartz is a third party app. Can't use this at office (Infosec policy). I need a simple batch program that does not need any clearance from the Infosec team since a batch program is not a third-party app. Hope this helps.

Comment: OK give me some time. I will edit the above answer that might help you for your situation.

Comment: I appreciate your help MohdAdnan. But how will I be able to use a java logic in a batch program? Sorry, but I do not have a programming background. I do not know how to use a timer function in dos else I would have done it myself.

Comment: you need to change this line by this <br/>
 timer.schedule(new PrintTask(), 5*60*1000);<br/>
and replace run method to put your file copy logic. You can use java File copy APIs to do that.
I can't write a production ready code here because I don't know about your project details.

Comment: see the commented portion of run method. you need to replace that portion to file copy logic.